# How to create a custom text selector with React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I'm building an epub reader (using this package: https://github.com/victorsoares96/epubjs-react-native), and I want to create a custom text selector with context menu in my application.

The text selector context menu should have a copy option and add an option that calls a javascript function(like a highlight function, for example). I'm building an react-native app.

I don't find the answer anywhere.

Can someone help me?

I want to creat something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RrTN.png)

I don't know java, just javascript, react, react-native and redux...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like possibly this is [a page that demos a solution](https://morioh.com/p/20d43f77ffd1), and leads [to this repo](https://github.com/Astrocoders/react-native-selectable-text), which is archived, but may help

also [mentioned here in this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48883406/react-native-add-option-to-text-context-menu)

Comment: Thank you, but I need it for react-native, not react. Thanks!

Comment: did a bit more searching, and edited my answer above

Comment: Thank you very much, but this only works with texts. I need it to work with an epub reader component. Maybe, the solution would have to be something native. However, I don't know how to program java for android, nor swift for ios. I'm really in need of help creating this custom text context menu. :/

Comment: So which epub reader component are you using? I'd say put the question to them, in their repo? or mention it here so people know which one it is

Comment: this one: https://github.com/victorsoares96/epubjs-react-native